# How can I prevent my condensation tubing from freezing outside?

Tags: pipe, freezing, condensation

I apologize if I missed the answer for this. My plastic condensation drain tube froze outside and the water in my condesation pump could not drain correctly. I hardly touched the tube and it snapped and started spraying. This is how I discovered it was frozen....I let it drain and taped it with electrcal tape when it stopped. I located the frozen part and thawed with hot water. This fixed the problem temporarily because the condensation pump stopped running and was not filled with water anymore.

It is going to refreeze tonight. I need to know what to get to patch the hole I taped and what kind of insulation is best so it will not refreeze. I live in southern Pa and it has been below freezing for days. Tomorrow is supposed to be above 40 so I want to fix it.

Comment: Is this for like a condensing boiler or furnace? If so, it is probably located indoors. Could you re-route the condensate tubing to an indoor location at least as a temporary measure?